# Cauchy sequences of real and rationals

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_n \in \mathbb{R})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a cauchy sequence of reals.

Each number in the sequence is an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers. That is, $x_n = \left[x_{n, m} \in \mathbb{Q} \right]_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ under the usual equivalence relation between Cauchy sequences.

The equivalence class may contain several Cauchy sequences which are "equivalent" to each other. Any one of such Cauchy sequences $(x_{n, m} \in \mathbb{Q})_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ can be a "representative" for the real number $x_n$.

Is it possible to find a representative $(x_{n, m} \in \mathbb{Q})_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim x_{n,n} \neq \lim x_n$?

Comment: Your thoughts? Ideas? You think it is true or not? What did you try?

Comment: My professor said during lectures it is possible and left as an optional exercise to think about it. I tried $x_n = e^{-n}$ and $x_{n, m} = \left (\left (1 + \frac{1}{m} \right )^m \right)^{-n}$ but the equality holds.

Comment: Really? But $x_{n,n} = (1 + \frac{1}{n})$ converge to 1 where $x_n$ goes to 0?

Comment: Isn't $(2^n)^{-n} = 2^{-n^2}$ and NOT $(2^n)^{-n} = 2$?

Comment: Oh, yes, pardon me. I got carried away :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is my try for redemption. Consider:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
x_1 &:= 1,12345 \dots ,
\\
x_2 &:= 1,02345 \dots,
\\
x_3 & := 1,00345 \dots,
\\
\dots
\end{aligned} 
$$
Then $x_n \to 1$. Now consider the following cauchy sequences
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_{nm} := 
\begin{cases}
1,\underbrace{0\dots0}_{n-1}n \,(n+1) \dots m\,  0 \dots & n < m
\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
So for example we have $x_{35} = 1,0034500\dots$ . So $x_{nm} \to x_n$, right? But in particular $x_{nn} = 0$ and so $x_{nn} \to 0$.

It seems to me this works?

Comment: Thanks. The only trick is the piecewise expression. So If I have $x_1 = 1.9, x_2 = 1.99, x_3 = 1.999, ...$ and have $x_{n, m} = x_n$ when m > n and $x_{m, n} = 0$ otherwise. Would that work also.

Comment: Yes, that also should work. Indeed, I think that even works for a constant series, $1= x_1=x_2 = \dots$.